# Why can't I use notifyAll() to wake up a waiting thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have a thread class having the following two methods:

```
public void run()
{
    boolean running=true;
    while(running)
    {
        sendImage();
    }
}

private synchronized void sendImage()
{
        if(!imageready.getFlag())
        { 
            try
            {
                wait();
                System.out.println("woke up!");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception raises in ImgSender while waiting");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //send image
        }
}
```

I also has a GUI part with a mouse click method to open the file chooser window to let user choose file. The code

```
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event) 
        {
           chooser=new JFileChooser();

           int status=chooser.showOpenDialog(null);


           if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
           { 
               try
               {
                    prepareImage();
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   System.out.println("file not opened");
                }
            }
         }

   private synchronized void prepareImage() throws Exception
    {
           System.out.println("File chosen");
           imgFile=chooser.getSelectedFile();  
           image.setImg( ImageIO.read(imgFile) );
           imageready.setFlag(true);
           notifyAll();  
           System.out.println("noticed other threads");
    }
```

But I can't wake the first thread up using the notifyAll() so that it could send the image.

Comment: You haven't synchronised around the same locking object...

Comment: You might be able o use a BlockingQueue instead

Comment: Are the `wait` and `notifyAll` calls on the same Object?

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by "same locking object"?

Comment: @copeg no it's in different object.The GUI part is in a panel object while the first part is in a class called ImageSender.

Comment: @CheuckKwanLee From what I can tell, the "thread" class and the "gui" class are two different objects, so they have nothing in common, so call `notifyAll` on the GUI class has no means by which to communicate that to the "thread" class.  Instead, you need to be using a common (same instance) lock object

Comment: @CheuckKwanLee You may like to take a closer look at [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MadProgrammer mentioned, you are not synchronizing on the same lock.  A lock is, well, not sure how else to describe it.  It's a lock.  To lock and wait in Java, you pick an object to represent the "lock".

If 2 threads synchronize on 2 different objects, it's like the first thread saying "I am pumping gas in pump #1, if you need to use it, get in line", then the second thread saying "Hey, let me know when you're done with #2" (when pump 2 is out of service).

If you want the second driver to wait for the first driver to finish pumping, then he needs to declare interest in pump #1, the same pump that is being held by someone else.  Likewise, if you want 2 threads to successfully perform a wait and notify, they need to refer to the same object.

Why this may appear confusing in your situation is that you aren't specifying *explicit* objects to lock on.  You declared your methods as `synchronized`, which implicitly uses **the instance of the object the method is executing against** as the lock resource.

```
public class LockTest implements Runnable {
    public void synchronized doNothing() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting lock...");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Releasing lock...");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LockTest test1 = new LockTest();
        LockTest test2 = new LockTest();
        new Thread(test1).start();
        new Thread(test2).start();
        // Notice from the output that the threads do not block each other.
    }
}
```

We created 2 instances of `LockTest`, so they do not block each other since they have completely independent locks.

```
public class LockTest implements Runnable {
    private Object thingToLockWith;

    public LockTest(Object thingToLockWith) {
        this.thingToLockWith = thingToLockWith;
    }

    public void doNothing() {
        synchronized (thingToLockWith) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Starting lock...");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("Releasing lock...");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object lock = new Object();

        LockTest test1 = new LockTest(lock);
        LockTest test2 = new LockTest(lock);
        new Thread(test1).start();
        new Thread(test2).start();
        // Notice from the output they block.
    }
```

See how the output differs.  The second thread has to wait in line for the first thread.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use threads API directly in Swing applications, use [Swing workers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) instead, simply create instance of one when you need to do background task, like sending image and you don't want to block GUI thread

Comment: From what we can gather, there is a separate `Thread` class and a separate GUI class.  Since the thread class doesn't seem to interact directly with the UI, there doesn't seem to be much need for a `SwingWorker`

Comment: Swing framework already has a mechanism which allows to run background tasks triggered by UI, why not using it?

Comment: SwingWorker is more or less, intended to allow the background thread to update the UI more safely, generally not the other way round, just saying you're adding complexity to a problem which doesn't provide any real benefits ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are waiting on a the thread object and the gui object is doing the notify.

So when you do `notifyAll();` do not expect that waiting on the thread object to wake up, as that is a completely different lock.

You can just use a common lock.