# all values are printing through one thread only

Tags: java, multithreading

Thread- 0 which is waiting to start again(in wait state) is not starting even after hitting notify by another Thread.can someone helps me with the below code.

Trying to print the numbers by using two threads thread-0, thread-1 but once the thread had gone to waiting  state it's not starting even after calling notify by another thread

```
package com.chan.newFeature;
class ValuePrinter  implements  Runnable
{

    private volatile  static int maxValue=1;
    private int reminder;
    public ValuePrinter(int reminder) {
        this.reminder = reminder;
    }
    public ValuePrinter() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(maxValue<20){
            synchronized (this){
             //   System.out.println("maxValue "+maxValue);
            /*if (maxValue%2==0)
                printEven();
            else
                printOdd();*/
            if (maxValue%2==reminder){
                try {
                   System.out.println("Inside Synchronized Context Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+maxValue);
                   this.wait();
                    System.out.println("Inside Synchronized Context after wait Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+maxValue);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
           //     System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getName()"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+maxValue+":"+reminder);
                this.notify();
                System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() :");
                maxValue=maxValue+1;
            }
        }
    }


}







public class OddEvenExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValuePrinter valuePrinter=new ValuePrinter(2);
        ValuePrinter valuePrinter2=new ValuePrinter(1);
        Thread t1=new Thread(valuePrinter);
        Thread t2=new Thread(valuePrinter2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:1:2
Inside Synchronized Context Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-1:1
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:2:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:3:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:4:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:5:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:6:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:7:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:8:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:9:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:10:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:11:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:12:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:13:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:14:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:15:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:16:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:17:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:18:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
Thread.currentThread().getName() :Thread-0:19:2
Thread.currentThread().getName() :
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer: this, "replace notify() by notifyAll()" is not the correct answer but the problem is here: [Why can't I use notifyAll() to wake up a waiting thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292416/why-cant-i-use-notifyall-to-wake-up-a-waiting-thread) You are creating two objects they are independent and not in the same lock. Simply speaking, your notify only refers to that specific object thread.

And here, I got the answer for what you want:

```
static Object lock = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {

     while(maxValue<50){
            synchronized (lock){
             //   System.out.println("maxValue "+maxValue);
            /*if (maxValue%2==0)
                printEven();
            else
                printOdd();*/
            if (maxValue%2==reminder){
                try {
                   System.out.println("Inside Synchronized Context Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+maxValue);
                   lock.wait();
                   System.out.println("Inside Synchronized Context after wait Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+maxValue);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getName() :"+Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+maxValue+":"+reminder);
            lock.notifyAll();
            maxValue=maxValue+1;
            }
        }

}
```

Adding one static object property for the common lock so Lock this object instead of self thread. Let me know if this is not working.

Comment: In an output, It's very clear that one of the thread gets a chance to enter in the  if Block and gone in waiting state and mean time another thread got a chance for execution(Because Lock got free) even that thread is hitting notify continiously still the thred which gone in waiting state  it's not getting notified and gone to infinite waiting state.Please tell me the reason for that.? because there is only two thread we can use notify

Comment: Notify() is for a specific thread so in your case it is multithreading, for example, threadA.Notify(). Ref. https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify

Comment: so you think notifyAll will resolve the problem. I will request you to once execute the Example with notitifyAll for me even after putting notifyAll the output will be same..can you answer my first Question why the thread which is gone to wait state is not comming back after even calling notifyAlll as you said...By the way notify will release 1 thread from the group of thread which are in wait state.

Comment: yes yours updated reply helped me. :) Thanks  Wing Kui Tsoi